# Testing Complex structures

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, expression-trees

I'm working on small documents compiler. I'm using .NET expression trees to create code that will generate documents. I think that it is impossible to write Unit tests which test generated expression trees structures as it is just code and I can write it in many ways to get same result.
I think that the only solution is to write integration tests that will run documents compilation and execution and check output result. 
I want to know if integration testing is the only one option in this situation?

Comment: It would be useful to know how this system is implemented (specifically the language used).

Comment: Just updated. I'm using .Net (C#)

Comment: I added some tags so that the appropriate people can find your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think that it is impossible to write Unit tests which test generated
>   expression trees structures as it is just code

I don't agree.

You need two tests for each input case: one to ensure that the generated expression tree is produced for a known input and another to check the code that's emitted when you walk the AST.  "Impossible"?  Hardly.

Comment: Hmm, yes, I'm agree that it is possible, however is it worth it to check expression tree. Any minor update in internal code implementation will cause red tests even if it is right code.

Comment: What's the alternative?  Not checking it?  Will it be easier to find out that your ATS generation is broken in a unit test or bad generated code?  I'd prefer the first one.  Yes, of course you have to maintain the tests along with the code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The alternative is in writing integration tests as I wrote in my question. Of course tests will depend on AST generator and documents creation code.